# c# using python.net run python execution flow

Tags: c#, python.net

I have a development task with the following details:

Users should be able to drag and drop nodes on a canvas to design the execution sequence of Python algorithms.
The output of one algorithm serves as the input to another.
Nodes on the canvas should display the current execution status through colors: executed nodes should be green, nodes currently executing 4. 4. should flash in a non-green color, and nodes not yet executed should be gray
[details shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ayw9.png)

If anyone could provide me with some advice, tips, or even a runnable demo, it would be immensely helpful. Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.